# Sharepoint 2013 External Login

Tags: 2013, authentication, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, membership-provider

I have to login users in a SharePoint publishing site, using an external site which provides me this:

[image]

The steps are:

1. User wants to login, I redirect them to an external site.(ex: **_http://externalsite.com/login.aspx?returnUrl=mySite**)
2. If succeded, it returns to an url from my site, with a token(ex: **_http://mysp.com/landing.aspx?token=123456**)
3. I send this token to an external web service, which will answer me with user data.
4. Once I have this data, I set up the user info on my Application and this is the end of the process.

I've already have this working on an ASP.NET site, but I can't figure out how to accomplish this on a SharePoint site.

I've also read some documentation and [blog post](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/) but all of them talks about custom providers like SqlMembershipProviders, [Claims](http://blog.podrezo.com/sharepoint-custom-claims-provider/), and lot of stuff that I find not useful for this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Chuck Norris (nice pseudo, btw),

In your case (authentication through an external web site), you're probably better off writing a custom Security Token Service and register it with SharePoint.

You can find some information about developing such a piece of software at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347547.aspx.

Contact me offline at Info at RioLinx Dot Com and I'll send you a presentation that goes through the process of setting up a custom STS with SharePoint.

Raphael.